# Warning in Chrome for updating "value" attribute in React without onChange

Tags: reactjs, onchange

I am creating a form. There is a radio input that chooses the value of the next input. The code works are written, but I get  a warning in the Chrome console. I've tried adding onChange() several different ways but all I get are errors. How do I fix this warning.

```
const [lyeConcentration, setLyeConcentration] = useState("33.33%");
const [lyeUnits, setLyeUnits] = useState("percentage");

  <div onChange={e => setLyeConcentration(e.target.value)}>
  <input type="radio" id="lyePercentage" name="lyeUnits" value="33.33%" defaultChecked />
  Percentage
  <input type="radio" id="lyeRatio" name="lyeUnits" value="2:1" />
  Ratio
</div>
<div>
  <label htmlFor="lyeConcentration">Lye Concentration</label>
  <input id="lyeConcentration" value={lyeConcentration} type="text" className="lyeConcentration" autoComplete="off" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below, i added onChange to both radio input and the text input.
I think its actually complaning about the text input.

```
  const [lyeConcentration, setLyeConcentration] = useState("33.33%");
  const [lyeUnits, setLyeUnits] = useState("percentage");

  return (
    <>
    <div>
     <input type="radio" id="lyePercentage" name="lyeUnits" value="33.33%" onChange={e => setLyeConcentration(e.target.value)} defaultChecked />
    Percentage
     <input type="radio" id="lyeRatio" name="lyeUnits"  onChange={e => setLyeConcentration(e.target.value)} value="2:1" />
    Ratio
  </div>
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="lyeConcentration">Lye Concentration</label>
    <input id="lyeConcentration" value={lyeConcentration} type="text" className="lyeConcentration" autoComplete="off"  onChange={e => setLyeConcentration(e.target.value)}/>
  </div>
  </>
```

)